Classify data on unstructured texts using python
I'm going to give an introduction to the project surroundings so you have some context for helping me out.
I'm trying to parse out information of german organizational charts in pdf format. Right now I can reliably read out the content of the rectangles from the PDF and get all textblocks that are contained in that rectangle. For each rectangle, I want to sort the information inside it into several categories. These are:

Type (the type of the suborganization. e.g. Referat)

Title (the specific name of the suborganization. e.g. Referat XI A 9)

Description (the responsibilities. e.g. Personalien der Zollverwaltung und der Bundesmonopolverwaltung für Branntwein)

Person in charge (e.g. MR Hoffmann)


I looked into several different approaches using python but I couldn't find a fitting solution. With spacy I found it hard to get any meaningful results because the text inside a rectangle isn't a real sentence and, as far as I understand, spacy relies on identifying the part-of-speech a token has in a sentence.
I read into some other approaches using bag-of-words for example but this also doesn't seem to make sense because I again don't have full sentences. I'm currently implementing a really large but simple pattern matching solution where I check for keywords like "Referat" or the prefix of a person "MR" and categorize based on that. This regex-approach obviously fails pretty quickly as soon as I don't have a specified prefix or keyword to search for in the given text.
I also tried taking into account at which positions the textblocks are placed inside the content node and parse the information based on that. But this approach fails as soon as the order differs between the pdfs.
I'm looking for general advice that points me to a solution for this problem using python. The questions regarding this topic seems to be very old or focus only on a subset of the problems that I have so I think it would be helpful to have another discussion.

Have you tried to process the org charts as an image with one of the current LLMs with vision capabilities? E.g. GPT-4o or Claude Sonnet v3.5?

@petezurich we can parse the text from the orgchart quiet well actually and we are also able to sort them to their corresponding boxes. Lots of manual work but it works.
The problem is the semantic analysis of the content inside the boxes as they are unstructured and have no context for nlp or similar solutions
